# Uploading and Viewing Form Data with C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I'm trying to post form data to an ASP.NET WebForms application and open the form with the posted data. The code below was found on a post on these forums.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient ())
{
  var reqparm = new NameValueCollection ();

  reqparm.Add ("WorkOrder", TextBox_WorkOrder.Text);
  reqparm.Add ("Account", TextBox_Account.Text);

  byte [] responsebytes = client.UploadValues ("http://www.website.com/form.aspx", "POST", reqparm);
  string responsebody = Encoding.UTF8.GetString (responsebytes);
}
```

Comment: What do you need help with?  Is the code not working?  Do you not understand it?  Was there any explanation with the code you found?

Comment: What's exact issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above code works great as a Windows app posting data to a form. What I was looking for was a way to open a new web form and post data to it. This is easily done with sessions in ASP.NET:

### Form1.aspx

```
Session ["Name"] = TextBox_Name.Text;
```

### Form2.aspx

```
TextBox_Name.Text = (string) Session ["Name"];
```

I was trying to find a solution in ASP.NET that would do the same thing without sessions.